# Match Sentences in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching, text-mining, string-matching

I have 2 tables. Table1 is a smaller table with around 10K values.
Table 1 (Sample):

```
KeyWords                         PageView
Phillips Trimmer                123
Buy Samsung Mobile              45
Ripe yellow Banana              63
Pepsi                           140
```

Table 2 contains 1 Million Values.

Table 2 (Sample):

```
KeyWords                         PageView
Electric Trimmer                123
Samsung Mobile                  45
Yellow Ripe Banana              63
Samsung S6                      304
Banana                          105
Phillips                        209
Trimmer Phillips                29
```

Now I want to take all words from table 1 and look into table 2 an find the best match. The order of words should not have a big influence in the match i.e "Ripe yellow Banana" should match perfectly with "Yellow Ripe Banana". "Buy Samsung Mobile" should match with "Samsung Mobile" and with "Samsung S6".

The final output should look like this.

Table 3:

```
Word                            PageView   Match
Phillips Trimmer                123        Trimmer Phillips
Buy Samsung Mobile              45         Samsung Mobile
Ripe yellow Banana              63         Yellow Ripe Banana
Pepsi                           140        NA
```

Would really appreciate if we can Stem and Tokenize the sentence before doing a match.

I have tried the following but its not working properly and the loop takes quite a bit of time.

```
file_1$match <- ""
for(i in 1:dim(file_1)[1]) {
print(i)
x <- grep(file_1$Keywords[i],file_2$Keyword,value = T, ignore.case = m 
T,useBytes = T)
x <- paste0(x,"")
file_1$match[i] <- x
}
```

- I have tried using 'agrep' as well varying the 'max.distance' parameter. The results were not as expected.

Comment: Do you expect to have several matches ? For example: "Samsung S6" and "Samsung Mobile" in Table 2 will both match "Buy Samsung Mobile" from Table 1.

Comment: does pageview have anything to do with the matching? for Phillips Trimmer, I thought a better match will be Electric Trimmer because they both have the same PageView?!

Comment: @bVa I expect to have the best match only i.e only 1 match.
 PageView has nothing to do with the match. That's just an additional column I have.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I used the "apply" function to perform the following on every row of tab1:
the function inside "apply", takes x[1] which is keyword (let's say "Ripe Yellow Banana"), strsplit splits it by space ("Ripe" "Yellow" "Banana"), sapply performs grepl on each of these splits to see if the pattern exists in tab2. so you will have 3 column of true falses for "Ripe" "Yellow" "Banana". next step is to count the number of trues for each row and output the tab2 with that row number.  I also put a if statement to give NA's if the max number of trues is 0:

```
tab1<-data.frame(Keyword=c("Phillips Trimmer",
                 "Buy Samsung Mobile","Ripe Yellow Banana","Pepsi"),
                 PageView=c(123,45,63,140))

tab2<-data.frame(Keyword=c("Electric Trimmer","Samsung Mobile",
                 "Yellow Ripe Banana","Samsung S6","Banana",
                  "Phillips","Trimmer Phillips","Buy Trimmer Philips"),
                 PageView=c(123,45,63,304,105,209,29,21))

tab2$StrLen<-apply(tab2,1,function(x)length(unlist(strsplit(x[1], " "))))
tab1$BestMatch<-apply(tab1,1,function(x){
  a <-sapply(unlist(strsplit(x[1], " ")), grepl, tab2$Keyword)
  a<-cbind(a,TRUECnt=rowSums(a==TRUE))
  a<-as.data.frame(a)
  a$StrLen <- length(unlist(strsplit(x[1], " ")))

  if (max(a$TRUECnt)==0){
    return(NA)
  }
  return(as.character(tab2[which(a$TRUECnt==max(a$TRUECnt) &
                                 tab2$StrLen <= a$StrLen),]$Keyword))

})

View(tab1)    View(tab1)
       #              Keyword PageView          BestMatch
       # 1   Phillips Trimmer      123   Trimmer Phillips
       # 2 Buy Samsung Mobile       45     Samsung Mobile
       # 3 Ripe Yellow Banana       63 Yellow Ripe Banana
       # 4              Pepsi      140               <NA>
```

Comment: When I am running the above code, it's giving me multiple match  for a single keyword. For example, if there is 'Phillips Trimmer' in table 1 and 'Trimmer Philips' as well as 'Buy Phillips Trimmer' in Table2, in the bestmatch column, I am getting both. What I need is 1 only match, which ever is the best.

Comment: hmm that's a very subjective decision what the best match is in this case! don't you think? why Trimmer Phillips is a better match than Buy Phillips Trimmer to your logic? you have to articulate your logic behind that decision so we can help you. one reason could be that you want the shorter phrase?

Comment: In "Buy Trimmer Philips", buy is an additional word. So if all the individual words match in the search string then i would rate it highest. If there is 1 or more extra word, I would rate it low. The same should happen if there is a word or 2 missing. So "Philips Trimmer" should match best with "Trimmer Philips" compared to "Buy Philips Trimmer" or "Philips". Out of "Buy Philips Trimmer" and "Philips", "Buy Philips Trimmer" should score more since it has both the word "Philips" and "trimmer" matched. I am ready to take any other logic if you have. But i finally need 1 match for 1 string.

Comment: @Rakesh Das the edit should solve that problem! choose it as the correct answer please if it does! thanks :)